# Jenkinsfile Pipeline (Declarative): Trigger my pipeline on push commits to a Github repo

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

I have a question about triggering my pipeline.

Github Repo A:

- contains my Jenkinsfile
- checks out Repo B
- executes script in Repo B

Github Repo B:

- containers scripts
- Will be executed as part of my pipeline

So I want this pipeline to be triggered every time a commit is pushed into Repo B, what is the best way to do that? Is using Github webhooks the best way to do this?

Comment: There are several ways you can do that, **Poll SCM**, **Trigger builds remotely** or even use plugins like **[GitHub](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/)**. The easiest one is to use **Trigger builds remotely** and Github webhooks on the repo to trigger it mainly because the job can be triggered with simple HTTP a GET request to the job URL (use a random token for a bit of an added security).

Comment: Okay, let me give that a try. Is there a wiki/link you can provide so I can do this?

Comment: That's the plugin I've linked. It needs to be configured system-wide so if you have 10 jobs that triggered by them and any one of those repos related jobs updates, all of them will start polling. It's not much far from **Poll SCM**.

Comment: Do you have a basic pipeline written? [Pipeline Syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)

Comment: There's not much documentation as to integrations as they depend on what plugin users use and what type of pipelines are in use. I.E. if you have something like Multi-branch Pipeline that's very different to a regular pipeline. This one gives basics of **Trigger builds remotely**. https://medium.com/@narenchejara/trigger-jenkins-job-remotely-using-jenkins-api-20973618a493

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My JenkinsFile was not in the same SCM I want to watch and trigger by BitBucket push.

```
SCM CodeBase   JenkinsFile.groovy
SCM SourceCpp  <project>
```

I tried to create declarative pipeline with JenkinsFile.groovy to be triggered for push into SourceCpp.

So far I have tried:

**Poll SCM** - does not work, I cannot specify what SCM to poll.
**Trigger builds remotely** - obvious security risk, cannot have API key in cleartext.
**GitHub** - not applicable for my BitBucket.
**Bitbucket webhook trigger** - cannot override SCM to SourceCpp
**Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket** - promising, but does not work/trigger despite I have overrided URL.

But there is a solution:

1. Create new FreeStyle job Dull_project with SCM SourceCpp.
2. Setup simple **Bitbucket webhook trigger** (or any other trigger you like) for its SCM changes.
3. In JenkinsFile job select trigger **Build after other projects are built**

or as a declarative syntax:

```
*triggers {
    // this is a hack to make dependency on SourceCpp.git work
    upstream 'Dull_project'
}*
```

Problem solved.